# How to distinguish OS X version in pkgbuild and productbuild

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, productbuild, pkgbuild

is it possible to distinguish the current OS X version during the installation of a PKG.
like:
if OS >= 10.9.0 install pkg_for_mavericks.pgk
else if < 10.9.0 install pgk_not_for_mavericks.pgk

In the past, with the legacy PackageMaker, it was possible to map requrements to a package like the required size, target OS X version and so on.

I didn't foudn any examples for the newer PKG-File createion with the commandline utilities pkgmaker and productbuild style

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Build package using productbuild with --distribution parameter. 
Use 'choice' with 'selected' parameter in Distribution file like this: selected="system.compareVersions(system.version.ProductVersion, '10.9') >=0"
Documentation for Distribution file is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html